# Make explorer not hang when waiting on i/o, network locations etc

Tags: windows

When I started using windows, I was a little puzzled that the most popular operating system in the world, and its file browser, that millions would use every day, would amateurishly lock up all windows and the desktop whenever it gets stuck waiting for something like a network resource (to time out, because its down), but i decided to give them a break, surely it will improve.

Well, its been 20 years, we have these things called threads now, pretty mainstream even, and...

Is there at least a way to configure explorer in Windows 10 so that when the computer has booted up, and I simply open an explorer window, and click This PC, it doesn't hang for a good 10 seconds or so (presumably looking for down network drives or something).

It would be nice that if it did insist on locking up the whole process while it waited for an i/o resource, that it at least only did so when I explicitly tried to interact with that resource.

Comment: Explorer itself can't do that. But I bet there are programs out there that work better in this regard.

Comment: Windows 10?....

Comment: Yep Windows 10 is what I'm using atm. But similar issues also affect  8.1, 8, 7, Vista, XP, 2000...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with such problem, which brought me to following solutions:

1. I decided to leverage "sleep" capability of server, so it goes to sleep when nobody is using it.
2. I made script that wakes server and mounts desired network drive, so I don't have to wait for explorer timeout.

Script is available on [my github repo](https://github.com/p0rc0jet/serverWaker).
Initially it was script that on run checked if network drive is mounted and unmounted it. Funny thing, if you unmount network drive via shell you don't have to wait ;)

In your case you can automatically unmount network drives on shutdown/sleep,  and remount on startup/wake up, but on mount script considers if server is available and doesn't freeze explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "Network" at the bottom left of Explorer. That browses to all possible locations that the computer knows about / are nearby / and possibly cached.

That is why it is slow and always has been. Because of what it tries to browse, you cannot really speed it up.

I consciously do not click on Network unless I need to and am prepared to wait.

I have not seen much change in this function over time.

Even Explorer stand-ins (say xPlorer2) are no better in my experience.

Comment: nah I don't even have network discovery on. I think its network drives, I get this problem just clicking on 'This PC' (AKA My Computer back in the day)

as an asside, I'm not expecting it to do its network searching 'quicker', I know it has to wait for timeouts, what I'm expecting is it not to lockup ("not responding") the entire explorer UI - desktop and all sometimes.  It should be able to do the netscan on a seperate thread, and simply have little pinwheels next to the network drives / locations it is 'loading'

Comment: In a command prompt, type NET USE  .   Does anything show up after NET USE  ?

Comment: yep, a mapped network drive. This is a work computer, and im working from home, the network drive is on the work local network, so its only available when I'm connected to the work VPN when at home.

My process just then: ran NET USE, it said the drive was unavailable. opened explorer, went to my computer, waited for it to "load" (waiting for timeout I think), showed the net drive as unconnected (even though im now connected to the VPN. double clicked on net drive, it opened fine, it now shows as connected, and I don't get the hang when opening explorer

Comment: Open a command prompt and type NET USE  X: /delete where X is the drive